# Intersection of matern covariance functions with different parameters

Tags: covariance, spatial, function, spatial-correlation

I am trying to prove some ideas about the identifiability of covariance function parameters for small samples. From various numerical experiments, it seems that the graphs of two matern covariance functions with different parameters (we may assume $\sigma^2=1$ for both) will intersect at most once on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Any insights as to whether this is definitively true, or how to show this? I have been staring at recurrence relations and derivatives of the modified Bessel function for days now, and no juice.

Edit as suggested by commenter @whuber:

I am interested less in estimation than in a more causal inference notion of identifiability: that is, assuming that we can fully observe certain population parameters such as $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ or $\text{Var } Z$, where $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed to be a Gaussian process with a particular parametric (say, Matern) covariance, are we able to identify the parameters from the observed population parameter?

In the simplest situation relevant to my research, we assume that $\text{Var } Z$ is observed and that $\sigma^2=1$ (the nugget is trivial). Now, we say that a model specifying a family of covariance functions (such as the Matern, exponential, wave family covariance functions) for $Z$ is identifiable if there do not exist two set of parameters that may give rise to population parameter $\text{Var } Z$.

Therefore, the model with the exponential covariance is identifiable so long as there is one nonzero distance because $e^{-w/\phi}=e^{-w/\phi'}$ for nonzero $w$ only if $\phi = \phi'$.

On the other hand, it can be shown that two wave covariance function with distinct parameters intersect at an infinite number of points, and for my purposes we consider the wave covariance function to not allow identifiability.

I believe that two Matern covariance functions with different range and shape may intersect on more than one point only if they are in fact identical. (Otherwise, if they differ only in range or only in shape, one will dominate the other on $\mathbb{R}^+$. This is easy to show.)

Comment: Could you explain why intersection (presumably of their graphs) might be relevant for estimating covariance functions?  And where you talk about two such functions with "different parameters," are you allowing both for differences of shape and range?

Comment: Yep, thanks for the suggestion! I am allowing for difference of shape and range. Otherwise they cannot intersect at all on the positive real numbers and in fact one will dominate the other.

Comment: That's exactly why I was wondering :-).